# Pipe line different behaviours for sort and grep

Tags: linux, pipe, streaming

It is strange to me that pipe line `|` behaves differently for the following commands:

```
curl http://norvig.com/big.txt |  sort


curl http://norvig.com/big.txt |  grep employ
```

In the first command, the pipeline waits until the `curl` execution terminates. While in the second command, it passes the intermediate output into `grep` while `curl` is running.

What does determine how pipe line behaves?

**UPDATE:**

The problem is not what `sort` and `grep` can do. The problem is how the pipe line knows it?

Comment: It seems obvious to me. How can `sort` start sorting if the input is not complete(still reading input)? while `grep` can starting working once there's any input at all.

Comment: @DavidDai That comment should be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason is as following:

`sort` cannot start sorting(or at least cannot start printing result) until it finishes reading input.

`grep` can starting working & start printing result once it starts getting input.

Comment: Hi David. The problem is not what `sort` and `grep` can do. The problem is how the pipe line knows it?

Comment: @ar2015 the pipe line doesn't know it. Both process(curl, sort) are started simultaneously and connected through the pipe, it is `sort` that waits till it reaches EOF  of the pipe to start sorting data(or printing result).

Comment: in other words, it's not the pipe that behaves differently, it's that sort and grep behaves differently when consuming input from a pipe.